# How to get the paths in the recursion call

Tags: algorithm, recursion

A child is running up a staircase with n steps, and can go either 1 steps, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Now write a program to count how many possible ways the child can run the stairs.

the solution looks like this ( DP can be used to save time )

```
public static int countDP(int n) {
 if (n<0)
   return 0;
 else if (n==0)
   return 1;   
 else {
   map[n] = countDP(n-1) + countDP(n-2) + countDP(n-3);
 return map[n]; }
}
```

Now the question is how to get those paths? for example for n=4 this function returns 7, how to get all the possible paths? (in this example 1111 - 121 - 112 - 211 - 31 - 13 - 22 )
Is there any way to do so by changing the current program?

This is not a homework question, it's coming from the Recursion and Dynamic Programming chapter of Cracking Coding Interview book - chapter 9 - Question 1.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @IMSoP, should we or should we not answer questions like this, if they look much like a home question copy/pasted into here?

Comment: @Roman There are guidelines for both asking and answering homework questions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This is not a homework question, it's coming from the Recursion and Dynamic Programming chapter of Cracking Coding Interview book - chapter 9 - Question 1.

Comment: You could reverse engineer the data from the map. Although it's much simpler to just write a recursive brute-force solution (and it's asymptotically optimal).

Comment: It doesn't really matter where it came from (well, the answers should differ, according to some people). Let me rephrase @IMSoP's comment - "This looks suspiciously like a question that was just copied from somewhere, without showing any attempt at solving it oneself, which is not appropriate for [so]".

Comment: @Dukeling : the map contains number of paths and not the paths, how to do reverse engineer that?

Comment: @user2925218 you don't really need to use map here (just a side note).
you could directly:
return countDP(n-1) + countDP(n-2) + countDP(n-3);

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways to find all paths, that can be implemented into your existing code.
First of all, this will be very costly, space-wise. Even for n=4, you need to create 7 paths.

I think, the best way is to create a ternary tree and assign each possible way that the path can go to each child node. 
So, here is a simple pseudo code:

```
root.value = 0;
root.left.value = 1;
root.middle.value = 2
root.right.value = 3;
```

Then when you do recursion, you would pass each child to an appropriate recursive call.

You would need to take care of some corner cases. 
Also, think about where you should define this ternary tree, considering you are using recursion.

NOTE: I didn't want to post actual code or give full answer, because several people (including myself) think it might be a homework question.  Because of that, I tried to help out with this question and lead the person to a solution without just handing it out.

Comment: When you do recursive calls, you are already making a tree, creating another tree doesn't look the best answer. I am looking for a way to use the recursion tree to get all the paths. This is not a homework question, it's coming from the Recursion and Dynamic Programming chapter of Cracking Coding Interview book - chapter 9 - Question 1.

Comment: @user2925218 to find all paths, you could perform a version of DFS that would go through all possible combinations in the tree. Once you hit a leaf node - print out (or store somewhere) the full path from root to the leaf node. That could give you a list of all paths. 
Link to DFS (just in case) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: the traversal in the code above is like DFS, the base conditions of recursion are the leaves (when n=0 or n < 0), I try to create the relevant string at leaf nodes, but it doesn't work, I am looking for a way to insert statements in this code that prints the paths properly, but I am not able to. let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: @user2925218 It will be difficult to create strings at leaf nodes or use some data structure that would hold the info internally because you have recursion.  Either substitute recursion with iteration(and use of some data structure that would store the info about current step)  or create a separate (global) tree that would be filled up, as you go, and then traverse it and get your paths.  You do traverse code in the tree-like manner, but you do not store any relevant info. Another words, you do not have any data structure that would store your path information. Hence, I believe, you need tree!